# Regex check in the Gatling simulation throws error

Tags: html, scala, gatling

For the below Html body,

```html
<p>You have <span>1</span> items in your cart.</p>

<p>
  Total
  <span
  >$24.99</span>
  items in your cart.
</p>
<p>
```

I have added the below check,

```
.check(regex("Total $$${cartTotal} items in your cart."))
```

For the same, I get the below error,

> "regex(Total $24.99 items in your cart.).find.exists, found nothing"

What check can we use here?
The demostore link - https://demostore.gatling.io/

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You've never validated any answer to all your previous questions. You have to do so if you want people to keep on helping you.

Comment: Okay, will do that.

Comment: I think the `regex` failed to match because of the `<span>` tags and new lines.

Comment: Okay, what else can be a good check here?

Comment: .check(regex(" $$${cartTotal}")) - Even this was failing.

Comment: @VargheseJohn Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers on how to properly use stackoverflow.